# Providing connection string to Linq-To-Sql data provider

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#, f#-3.0, dataprovider

Is there a way to provide a connection string to Linq-To-Sql data provider in F# from App.Config file.

I have tried the following just for testing:

```
let mutable connString = @"Data Source=PCSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NortwindDB;Integrated Security=True"
type SqlConnection = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString = connString>
```

but I get an error message "This is not a constant expression or valid custom attribute value"

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

The type provider itself requires a hard-coded connection string for generating the type (in your case `SqlConnection`) to develop against at compile time, but, you can configure the actual connection string used at runtime like so:

```
type SqlConnection = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=PCSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NortwindDB;Integrated Security=True">
let runtimeConnStr = ...
type dataContext = SqlConnection.GetDataContext(runtimeConnStr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using the "?ConnectionStringName" parameter will get you where you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362320(v=VS.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at the following question which has a solution for this in answers
[F# Type Providers and Continuous Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969181/f-type-providers-and-continuous-integration)